# Не могу подключить заголовочные файлы для внешней библиотеки в cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(hello-bin CXX)

add_executable(hello-bin-dynamic src/main.cxx)
target_compile_features(hello-bin-dynamic PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

target_link_libraries(hello-bin-dynamic dynamic.so)
```

пытаюсь линконуть библиотеку, которая находится в совершенно другой папке(в ней сама библиотека и папка include)

суть в том, что .h не подтягивается из папки[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну а почему они должны подтягиваться? вы где-то указывали где их искать? Это делается с помощью директивы target_include_directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кароч вот, напрямую указал путь к инклюдам, плюс тесты
здесь собирается 2 библиотеки (динамическая и статическая)
может кому-то поможет

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)

project(Hello-bin VERSION 1.0)
#--------------dyn
add_executable(Hello-bin-dyn ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cxx)

target_compile_features(Hello-bin-dyn PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(Hello-bin-dyn PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../hello_lib/include  )

target_link_libraries(Hello-bin-dyn   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../hello_lib/build/libHello-lib-dyn.so)

#-----------------stat
add_executable(Hello-bin-stat ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cxx)

target_compile_features(Hello-bin-stat PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_include_directories(Hello-bin-stat PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../hello_lib/include  )




target_link_libraries(Hello-bin-stat   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../hello_lib/build/libHello-lib-stat.a)

#--------------tests
include(CTest)
add_test(Test-dyn Hello-bin-dyn)
add_test(Test-stat Hello-bin-stat)
#set_tests_properties(Test-dyn PROPERTIES TIMEOUT ${MULTIPLY_TIMEOUT})

set_tests_properties(Test-dyn PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "hello, vertil")
set_tests_properties(Test-stat PROPERTIES PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "hello, vertil")
```